# Error "Incorrect syntax near 'order'" in partition over clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

What's causing this error?

In [SQL Server 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005), I am getting the error **Incorrect syntax near 'order'**. I have isolated the error to the `OVER clause` (the error goes away when I remove the 'order by' in the 'over' clause). I have reviewed the documentation and searched for a solution, but I can't find what the problem is.

```
SELECT bill.[cust_id], MONTH(bill.[del_date]), YEAR(bill.[del_date]),
   SUM(SUM(ISNULL(bill.[sum_count], 0))) OVER (PARTITION BY bill.[cust_id]
   ORDER BY YEAR(bill.[del_date]), MONTH(bill.[del_date])) AS QtyProcessed
FROM EnvelopeBilling bill
WHERE bill.[cust_id] = 1721
  AND bill.[del_date] BETWEEN '5/1/2015' AND '10/31/2015'
GROUP BY bill.[cust_id], MONTH(bill.[del_date]), YEAR(bill.[del_date])
ORDER BY bill.[cust_id], YEAR(bill.[del_date]), MONTH(bill.[del_date])
```

Comment: `SUM() OVER ()` doesn't have an order by...  `(1+2) == (2+1)`

Comment: You cannot use `SUM` with `OVER` and `Partition by..Orderby`, only with `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: He can use sum with ordering in sql servr 2012+

Comment: When I remove the order by, I get the total of all the months in the time period requested instead of the total for each month. How would I get the subtotal for each month? (and I'm stuck with 2005)

Comment: Ordering in window sum is not supported in 2005.

Comment: I removed the order by and added the year and month as part of the partition by and it worked. "PARTITION BY bill.cust_id, YEAR(bill.del_date), MONTH(bill.del_date)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'partition by' is the same as the 'group by', you should be able to just drop the partition by

```
SELECT bill.[cust_id] , MONTH(bill.[del_date]), YEAR(bill.[del_date]),
       SUM(ISNULL(bill.[sum_count], 0)) AS QtyProcessed
  FROM EnvelopeBilling bill
 WHERE bill.[cust_id]= 1721
   AND bill.[del_date] BETWEEN '5/1/2015' AND '10/31/2015'
 GROUP BY bill.[cust_id], YEAR(bill.[del_date]), MONTH(bill.[del_date])
 ORDER BY bill.[cust_id], YEAR(bill.[del_date]), MONTH(bill.[del_date])
```

Comment: I marked this up before I tested it (my bad). I get the error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." --See my last comment in my original post for the answer that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `SUM` with `OVER` and `Partition by..Orderby`, only with `PARTITION BY`. It doesnt make sense to order something that you want to sum.

```
SELECT bill.[cust_id], 
       Month(bill.[del_date]), 
       Year(bill.[del_date]), 
       Sum(Sum(Isnull(bill.[sum_count], 0))) 
         OVER (partition BY bill.[cust_id]) AS QtyProcessed 
FROM   envelopebilling bill 
WHERE  bill.[cust_id] = 1721 
       AND bill.[del_date] BETWEEN '5/1/2015' AND '10/31/2015' 
GROUP  BY bill.[cust_id], 
          Month(bill.[del_date]), 
          Year(bill.[del_date]) 
ORDER  BY bill.[cust_id], 
          Year(bill.[del_date]), 
          Month(bill.[del_date])
```

Comment: He can actually but from 2012. Running sum is the result of this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/023988/1

Comment: Don't know why this got a down vote.  Not your fault the question was not clear.  +1

Comment: Downvote because of `It doesnt make sense to order something that you want to sum.`. See the fiddle I provided for the sense.